# Confusion with variable expansion in Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I have the following hypthetical Makefile:

```
all: SOURCE = $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
unity: SOURCE = $(wildcard unity/*.cpp)

OBJECTS = $(SOURCE:.cpp=.o)

all: prog

unity: prog

prog: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(OBJECTS) -o prog
```

I need to compile with different source files / objects based on the initial target. It appears to me that variable expansion happens much earlier on the dependencies than in the target body as the above compiler command is called just fine with the right filenames, but the $OBJECTS in the prog dependency is still empty so none of the objects have been built.

The unity folder contains a combined source file with all other source files included for doing unity builds. This unity file is generated by the makefile, but this is left out and may in fact be multiple unity object files.

Is my design a lost cause? Am I going to have to resort to recursive make to achieve this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you want isn't possible, but I've generated dynamic header dependencies coverage integrated with make files, and never thought that was possible either. Take a peek at at the [gnu make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/) documentation. You may not get expansions like you like, but perhaps other targets can be created on the fly for you. It takes getting pretty damn crafty, but almost anything can happen in a make file.

Comment: The paragraph about "The unity folder" is highly unclear. If you clarify it, I'll bet we can find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. Because in general, there may be multiple targets which need to be built. On the commandline, or as an intermediate goal.
So setting the variable would be ambigous. Becasue of this, the values of target specific variables "are only available within the context of a target's command script (and in other target-specific assignments)." (see File: make.info,  Node: Target-specific)

But you can inspect the MAKECMDGOALS variable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're running into is that variables in RULES (targets and dependency lists) are expanded when the makefile is READ, while variables set for targets (like your $(SOURCES) above) are only set when the taget is triggered.  This means that target-specific variables are only useful in ACTIONS, since that's the only thing that happens after they are set.

That all said, you can get the effect you want by recursively invoking make:

```
all:
        $(MAKE) SOURCE="$(wildcard src/*.cpp)" prog
unity:
        $(MAKE) SOURCE="$(wildcard unity/*.cpp)" prog

OBJECTS = $(SOURCE:.cpp=.o)

prog: $(OBJECTS)
        $(CXX) $(OBJECTS) -o prog

.PHONY: all unity
```

but this is not something I would generally recommend.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use $SOURCE to mean different things depending on the make target executed.
You can gain a good understanding of makefiles parsing here:
http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reading-Makefiles

For your problem you have to define distinct variables for each type of source files.
For example:

```
all: SOURCE_ALL = $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
unity: SOURCE_UNITY = $(wildcard unity/*.cpp)

OBJECTS_ALL = $(SOURCE_ALL:.cpp=.o)
OBJECTS_UNITY = $(SOURCE_UNITY:.cpp=.o)
etc ...
```